# How to create a table of contents of specific embedded pdfs?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages, tagged-pdf

I have a master document with many included pdfs. Some of them are translations, which I have to create an index of.

Is there a way to tag the included pdfs and create a table of contents for them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor, etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Translated Documents}

%\tableoftranslateddocuments

\newpage 

\section{General Documentation}

This section contains the resume, a copy of the degree in Industrial Mechanical Engineering, and a copy of the degree of the Master in Business Administration. 

\subsection{Student Transcript}

\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Diplomas/escolaridad-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Diplomas/escolaridad-2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Diplomas/escolaridad-3.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Diplomas/escolaridad-4.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Diplomas/escolaridad-5.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Translations/student-transcript.pdf}%tag this as translation

\section{Employment Documentation}

The following pages show the work history of the applicant as it is registered by the Social Security Services (Banco de Previsión Social) of Uruguay.

\subsection{Record of Employment by the Social Security Bank of Uruguay (BPS)}

\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{Employment/historia-laboral.pdf}

\newpage

\subsection{Translation of the Record of Employment}

\includepdf[pages=-, angle=90, pagecommand={}]{Translations/employment-record-BPS.pdf}%tag this as translation


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you wanting one table of contents entry for each pdf, or are you wanting multiple table of contents entries for whatever would have had an entry in the included pdf's table of contents?

Comment: I want one table of contents that lists all the pdfs tagged as translations, indicating the page number in the master file, with one entry for each translation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I guess you are looking for a "List of PDFs" and not exactely a second table of contents. Adding a "list of ..." is quite easy. Here is one way to create a "list of ..." using the `float` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{pdfdoc}{h}{pdc}[section]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listof{pdfdoc}{My PDF documents}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\includepdf[
  pages = -,
  addtolist = {1, pdfdoc, Paper 1, pdf:paper1},
]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\includepdf[
  pages = -,
  addtolist = {1, pdfdoc, Paper 2, pdf:paper2},
]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach is

```tex
\includepdf[pagecommand={\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TOC Entry}}]{Diplomas/escolaridad-1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-]{Diplomas/escolaridad-1.pdf}
```

which I usually wrap into a macro.

`pdfpages` claims to allow `\includepdf[addtotoc={1,section,1,TOC Entry,mylabel}]`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks. However, that seems to add the included pdf in the main table of contents. What I want is to have two separate tables of contents. One with all the contents and another one listing only the specific included pdfs marked as translations.

Comment: I believe the `minitoc` package is designed to allow multiple tables of contents.  That would let you use the `pagecommand` to put the TOC entries where you want.